# java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed

Tags: java, sftp, inputstream, jsch, apache-commons-io

I am trying to transfer file from SFTP to SharePoint folder.
I have used JSCH Library to connect to SFTP.

Following is my code snippet to **upload file**.

```
private void sharePointUpload(String driveId, String targetLocation, InputStream inputStream, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    UploadSession uploadSession = this.graphServiceClient.drives().byId(driveId).root().itemWithPath(targetLocation +"/"+ fileName)
                                    .createUploadSession(this.uploadParams).buildRequest().post();
    byte[] inputStreamByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem> largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>
                                        (uploadSession, this.graphServiceClient, new ByteArrayInputStream(inputStreamByteArray), inputStreamByteArray.length, DriveItem.class);
    largeFileUploadTask.upload(MAXIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE);
}
```

I am getting error **java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed** at `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)`
What will be the root cause ?

Error Logs

[image]

**Update :**
Code Snippet to **Get InputStream**

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    sourcefilenamelist = list.get(i);
    logger.log(proccessingFileLogText + sourcefilenamelist);
    if (targetFilenameflag.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
        targetFilename = sourcefilenamelist;
    }
    
    InputStream stream = sourceChannelSftp.get(sourceLocation + '/' + sourcefilenamelist);
    InputStreamDetails decryptEncryptInputStreamDetails = decryptEncryptInputStream(stream, targetFilename, sourceEncryption, targetEncryption, jobjsource);
    stream = decryptEncryptInputStreamDetails.getInputStream();
    targetFilename = decryptEncryptInputStreamDetails.getFileName();
    
    try {
        sharePointUpload(targetDriveId, targetLocation, stream, targetFilename);
    } catch (ClientException e) {
        logger.log(" Graph API ClientException : ");
        logger.log( "e.getMessage()     :- " + e.getMessage() );
        logger.log( "RootCauseMessage   :- " + ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e) );
//                                      isSQSMessageRetry = true;
        throw e;
    }
...
...
...
}
```

**PS: Few files are transferred from List**

Comment: Root cause is that it says - `sharePointUpload ` was called with a closed `inputStream`.  You need to check/provide details of the code where this stream was created.

Comment: @Tintin Few files were transferred from List... I have added code to get file and method call

Comment: We need [mcve]. Have your question anything to do with SharePoint at all? What if you just read the `InputStream` in a loop without using any SharePoint code.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have mentioned error occurred while calling, `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)` which is in **sharePointUplod()**... nothing to do while uploading file to SharePoint.

Comment: So why do you complicate your question with SharePoint? Why don't you post a simple sequential code snippet that reproduces the problem? Instead of two disjoined methods with code that it not relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are providing it with closed InputStream when the method is being called. Make sure the InputStream you are providing is open and initialized.

Comment: Few files were transferred from List... I have added code to get file and method call

Answer (score 0):

This line is giving you a closed InputStream:

```
InputStream stream = sourceChannelSftp.get(sourceLocation + '/' + sourcefilenamelist);
```

Perhaps the `sourceLocation` argument that you are sending to it is not correct?

Comment: I mentioned **PS: Few files are transferred from List**... so I don't thing it is `sourceLocation` issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

supposing the stream works, but once the stream is read, it will close, try checking if it's being read somewhere else.